# Pop up message when sending large amounts of SMS messages

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, go-sms

When I send a relatively large number of text messages using GoSms, I get this pop up after I send a message:

[image]

I have seen this on other forums but I have yet to see a way to get rid of it (that is, without rooting the device, something I want to try to avoid). Anybody have any ideas to prevent this pop up from popping up?

Comment: This is a feature not problem.

Comment: IMHO it's a pretty stupid feature. There are a dozen other ways to exploit a user if he/she gives the correct permissions to an app without checking. It just causes extra clicks and comes without a big benefit.

Comment: @Flow: It's a good feature, maybe they could have done the implementation better. Think of apps with a piggy backed malicious sms spambot feature. That has actually already happened with pirated apps, which sent as much as they could and the user was charged. just can't find the source atm. This nag screen is the price for a sms spam free experience in the mobile world for all users.

Comment: [Smilar question with automation solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/166696/131553) - it should work for you unless you don't want automation as solution

Comment: You could try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.batterysaver) - well rated and recently updated

Answer (score 3):

The other alternative (or probably the best one too) is to use ADB shell which may work on a non-rooted device as well:

```
zeroflte:/ $ settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count 999999
zeroflte:/ $ settings put global sms_outgoing_check_interval_ms 900000099
```

Comment: didnt do anything for me

Comment: do i have root the phone for this to work?

Comment: @jim I personally tested it on a non-rooted Lenovo phone and it worked for me. The problem you have might be somewhere else.