# How can I send SMS to hundreds of users in my phone list?

Tags: applications, sms

How can I send SMS to 500 to 600 users in my contacts? This is usually done on a weekly or monthly basis.

Comment: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289)

Comment: I have Android Tablet, I have Android Phone. But how do i send to my all contacts at once SMS????? what is missing???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pop up message when sending large amounts of SMS messages](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38461/pop-up-message-when-sending-large-amounts-of-sms-messages)

Comment: @GAThrawn I don't think that's the problem here. User has not mentioned that issue.

Comment: Rephrased so it doesn't get closed.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try using gosms app, which has an option to select the contact book and send an sms.