# Blocking notification based on content or sticky-ness

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a messaging app (TextNow) that sometimes likes to put a sticky notification up (to notify me that I have used up my data and am being throttled), which I do not want and cannot be disabled in the apps settings.

Normally when an app abuses notifications like this I simply disable notifications for that app. However, in this case I would miss text messages if I did that. Therefor I was hoping for some way to either:

- Block notifications based on their content.
- For this specific app, only allow dismissable notifications.

I do have a rooted phone.

Example of the notification:

[image: A android screenshot with a single notification showing over that says “TextNow Wireless: You have reached your 4G data limit for the month, you are now on 2G data. Tap for more info.” and a button directly underneath that says “Open textnow”]

Note: I have posted an answer to this question, but I am still looking for better options.

Comment: What kind of notification is it? Mind mentioning the app and attach a screenshot?

Comment: @andy The app is TextNow (which I've now added to my post) and I've added a screenshot. I don't really know how to specify what kind of notification other than the fact that it's not dismissable; swiping it left or right does nothing. Hopefully the screenshot helps.

Comment: There is xposed module called GravityBox which have section Ultimate notification control. Is that helping? I don't know for sure if this can do what you want but it helped people to get rid of some notifications. Also if this is screenshot from your device than you have samsung device where xposed probably creates boot loop, so first google to see if xposed work on your device and than try installing framework and module mentioned above.

Comment: Also there is another Xposed module named [Notify Clean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.notifyclean) that may possibly allow you to filter notifications based on their content per your original request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a hacky way using an automation tool such as [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) or [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en). Others will also likely work, but I haven't tried them. First note that:

- This requires root.
- This will dismiss any other notifications that also happen to open from the same app at the same time.

Make a macro that:

1. Waits until the notification has been posted.

   - On MacroDroid, set a trigger for "Notification Received". Set the content to match the notification you want blocked.
   - On Automate, use a "Notification posted?" block with "Proceed" set to "When transition". On the flowchart, connect "No" to "In"
2. Disables notifications for the app.

   - On MacroDroid, use Configure App Notification > Disable
   - On Automate, use the "App notification set state" block, with "Notifications" set to "off"
3. Enables notifications for the app.

   - Same as above but enable (on) instead of disable.

Thanks to [beeshyam's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166696/blocking-notification-based-on-content-or-sticky-ness#comment213588_166696) for getting me most of the way there.

Comment: +1 for other app. Please see combined approach in the last part of my solution to override problem identified

Answer (score 3):

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) is  preferred option, since OP is looking for *context* based actions . Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid),  since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn (app guides you through the settings - make sure from the app settings you activate *ignore battery optimisations* if using Marshmallow)

OP has [confirmed in his answer that Macrodroid approach as suggested by me in comments worked](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/166889/131553) and his answer covers another automation app as well

You would need two macros for this to start with ( **needs root**)

First macro would look like this (Triggers / Actions / Constraints are added by **+**)

### Macro 1 :  Remove notification (name of macro )

**Trigger** : *Notification* → *Notification Received* → *Select Application* → *Choose App* → *Text Content* → *Contains* (Notification Text which you wish to disable)

**Actions**:

*Configure App Notifications* → *Choose App* →*Disable*

**Constraints**:  No Constraints

**Logic:** We need to identify  the content of notification  to disable this notification from appearing. Not specifying any Constraints means we want the macro to always run

In the next macro, we make sure that if the content of notification is anything else, that notification is shown

### Macro 2 :  Enable notification (name of macro )

**Trigger** : *Notification* → *Notification Received* → *Select Application* → *Choose App* → *Text Content* → *Excludes* (Notification Text which was disabled in earlier macro)

**Actions**:

*Configure App Notifications* → *Choose App* →*Enable*

**Note:**

1. Tested and working on Moto X Play, Android 6.0.1, with a different app, since app in OP doesn't work in country
2. In my experience, heavily modded OS's  like Samsung, Huawei, MIUI at times produce unexpected results, so it is better to have two separate macros - easier to troubleshoot from the app logs.

### Optimal approach

Once you have them working satisfactorily, you can *elegantly combine* above macros to have a *single macro* (not tested by me since I don't have any apps that produce multiple sticky notifications but should work). This is a *better approach*, since notifications aren't lost as pointed out by OP in his solution

> This will dismiss any other notifications that also happen to open from the same app at the same time.

**Macro  : Enable / Disable notification selectively**

**Trigger** : *Notification* → *Notification Received* → *Select Application* → *Choose App* → *Text Content* → *Any*

**Actions**:

*If Clause* → *Add Condition* →*Notification Present* → Select Application* → *Choose App* → *Text Content* → *Matches* ( Notification Text for which you wish to disable )

- Add Child action ( by long press of above action) of first Macro
- Add *else clause* ( long press *if*) and add action of second Macro