# How to disable Notifications for Github Emails on Google Inbox?

Tags: notifications, inbox-by-gmail

I turned the data synchronization on, and I get the notifications of Google Inbox. It works fine for "important" or "primary" emails, but it notifies me for Github emails too. How do I disable it -just because it is not really important/primary-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it from within the app as you can read in [Google Product Forums](https://support.google.com/inbox/forum/AAAAg4HSpy4mnE2a70Oy58/?hl=en) , open since last two years

Alternatively, you can try [automation](/questions/tagged/automation).  I prefer [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), being easy to learn and free (upto 5 macros)

Create a macro

**Trigger:** Notification → Notification received  → Select Application  → Inbox  → Text content contains  → *Enter here the text common to GitHub mails like maybe yourname@ GitHub.com?* ( Check your notifications to see what easily identifies these )

**Actions:**

1. Clear Notifications  → Clear all
2. *Optional if you don't want notification sound* Volume Change  → Set notification on slider scale to zero

**Constraints​ :** Leave blank

Comment: Thank you for the link and app. I am surprized that this issue has been discussed and nothing has been done yet. And for the email address: These emails come from the address notifications@github.com . I'll check the application, thank you

Comment: Welcome. Let me know if the problem is solved with macro ( should be ) and you can accept the answer on being sure

Comment: Yesterday I gave a try but I it didn't work. I guess "include" checks only the notification which doesn't have github or anything special to github. I will check more

Comment: It should work, as in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/166894/131553) trigger. Another alternative is to amend action which has clear notification > text content contain > notification@github.com. Yet another alternative is to say trigger just mention the app and text any with action as suggested above

Comment: Another troubleshooting way is to see if the macro is getting invoked or not by seeing the system log ( accessible from top left menu of main interface). You should see the macro with the name you saved it with and time it was invoked. Thanks for accepting but would have been appropriate to accept once it is solved :)