# How to block ads in Viber notifications?

Tags: viber-messenger

Is there any way to do it? Maybe a hidden setting or an a AdAway rule?
I'm talking about useless drivel that show up in notifications such as "Yay, new stickers for Valentine's Day!", etc. Turning off the notifications for Viber is not an option.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171669/131553) to prevent notifications; choose *exclude* option in trigger to retain notifications