# Does Android OS impose an SMS sending limit?

Tags: sms, sms-blocking

Is there an SMS sending limit? I have sent SMSs totaling >30,000 characters within 24 hours and am no longer able to send any SMSs (though I can receive them). Is my SMSC blocking me, or is the Android OS limiting how many SMSs I can send? If the latter is the case, how do I reset or increasing the SMS sending limit using `adb` ([`service call`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17580199/1429450)?)?

Comment: Related: [Pop up message when sending large amounts of SMS messages](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38461/44325)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. From

- Lynch, Doug. “[How to Change the SMS Limit on Android Without Root](https://www.xda-developers.com/change-sms-limit-android/).” *XDA Developers*, August 27, 2017:

> by default, Android will check to make sure you haven't sent more than 30 SMS messages to anyone within a span of 30 minutes.

> ### How to Change Android's SMS Limit
>
> 1. Set up ADB as outlined in [this previous tutorial](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/).
> 2. Enter an ADB shell by sending the following command in the command prompt or terminal window: `adb shell`
> 3. Then run the following command in the ADB shell to change the max SMS limit option: `settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count 5`
> 4. So in this example, I am actually reducing the number so Android warns me if I have sent more than 5 SMS messages within 30 minutes.
>    Change "5" to whatever number you want.
> 5. Next, you can run the following command to also change the time frame: `settings put global sms_outgoing_check_interval_ms 9000000`
>
>    [image: android sms limit]
> 6. And with this command I am reducing the time frame for this check from 30 minutes, to 15 minutes (this value is in milliseconds). You
>    can choose any integer value here for the time frame, just make sure
>    it's something sensible.